# Non stopping movement

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I've been having some trouble with player movement. The thing is, movement is controlled by four arrow-buttons and while one of them is pressed, the character moves in that direction. However, if the player doesn't lift his finger before moving away from the button, the player moves indefinitely. The code is the following:

```
function moveright(self,event)
    self.x=self.x+2
end

function rightkeypressed(event)
    if event.phase == "began" then
        knight.enterFrame = moveright
        Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",knight)
    end

    if event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "cancelled" then
        Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",knight)
    end
end

rightkey:addEventListener("touch",rightkeypressed)
```

This is the same for all four directions.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want to happen and include more of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple once you understand the touch listeners

```
if event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "cancelled" then
    knight.enterFrame = moveright 

    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",knight)
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",knight)
end
```

That should work if you have any questions or is not working just ask